# Installing Library Clion (SDL)

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I am currently trying to install the SDL library with C++ and Clion. I watched many youtube videos and googled the errors but still cannot find a way to fix this error.

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.1.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build D:\Programing\C++\School\HackClub\Day2\cmake-build-debug --target Day2 -- -j 6
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable Day2.exe
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2main
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\Day2.dir\build.make:95: Day2.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/Day2.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:89: CMakeFiles/Day2.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:123: Day2] Error
```

Here is my CMAKE file.

```
project(Day2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR D:\\Programing\\C++\\libs\\SDL\\include)
set(SDL2_LIBRARY D:\\Programing\\C++\\libs\\SDL\\lib\\x86)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} SDL2main SDL2)
```

Comment: `target_link_libraries` links with **libraries**, but in the first call you pass it `${SDL2_LIBRARY}` which is **directory** (`D:\\Programing\\C++\\libs\\SDL\\lib\\x86`). Do you mean `target_link_directories` instead of that call? The second call seems reasonable.. assuming you tell the linker where to search libraries `SDL2main` and `SDL2`.

Comment: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARY})` should probably be `target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARY})`. You should name your variables properly, i.e, you called it `SDL2_LIBRARY` when it is actually a directory and that prevented you from seeing the issue.

Comment: ```CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (target_link_directories):
  target_link_directories called with invalid arguments


mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:178: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```
Thank you for the help, I will need to go over the variable names. I however still get this error.

Forgive me for not being too good with CMAKE, I was just trying to install a library to play around with.

Comment: ```cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(Day2)



set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR D:\\Programing\\C++\\libs\\SDL\\include)
set(SDL2_DIR D:\\Programing\\C++\\libs\\SDL\\lib\\x86)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} SDL2main SDL2)
```

Comment: hello? I dont have a fix yet